# Both left and right scales in a single indicator

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, indicator, forex

I am new to trading and pine script and wanted to know is there a way to have an indicator with 2 scales and have them be able to interact with each other. I have seen a previous post on here that says that it is possible and wanted to know how I can make it work.

```
//@version=3

// EMA 3x1
// 3 EMA en 1 Indicador
// 3 Medias Móviles Exponenciales en un Indicador
// por Jesus Mercado

// @JesusMercado

//@version=3
study(shorttitle="EMA 3x1", title="3 EMA en 1 Indicador", overlay=true)
m1 = input(9, minval=1)
m2 = input(20, minval=1)
m3 = input(200, minval=1)

src = input(close, title="Source")

media_1 = ema(src, m1)
media_2 = ema(src, m2)
media_3 = ema(src, m3)

plot(media_1, color=green)
plot(media_2, color=red)
plot(media_3, color=blue)
```

here is the code that I am looking to add the left scale to and here is a picture of what I wanted to do [3EMA two scales](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tACZJ.jpg)

I am new to all of this and just wanted to ask how can this be done?

Comment: Version 3, really? Why not 5?

Comment: It was already an indicator on tradingview.